# Data in table is not updated from django-rest-framework UpdateAPIView?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

This is my update api view:

```
class CountlUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CountSerializers

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        queryset = Count.objects.filter(pk=id)

        return queryset
```

this is urls path

```
path('count/<int:pk>/update/', CountlUpdateView.as_view()),
```

This is my serializer class:

```
class CountSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Count
        fields = ('id', 'userId', 'channelId', 'rate')
```

When I hit my urls I got my rest framework update view form with put method. I update the field and click on put. Then I got the following message

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "userId": 4,
    "channelId": 10,
    "rate": 10
}
```

This is a correct update from my end. But when I check in the database then I found the old value and the data is not updated in the database.
What should I do so that data is updated in my database?

Comment: make a `PATCH` request, with the proper `id`?

Comment: How to do it. I learn this from a video tutorial. And pk is the row id in the database.